# Maximum/minimum values for two-dimensional type-II discrete cosine transform matrix

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, compression

When encoding a JPEG image, the pixels are encoded as an 8x8 matrix of values in the range [-128...127]. A two dimensional type-II DCT is applied to the matrix and the result is compressed further.

Is there a way to calculate the maximum and minimum output values for any given element of the the matrix? I need to analyse a matrix and determine if it is *possibly* the result of a DCT transform. If a value of a given element is 'out of bounds' then I can discard the data as it cannot possibly be output of a valid DCT transform.

Probably the best solution would be to perform a reverse DCT and see if any values are outside the range [-128...127] but most of the time I will not have the value of element at [0,0] available.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes doing inverse DCT if you have it available should work. But you should have other properties at your disposal. DCT2 should be orthogonal for example. But if it is also normalized or not will determine max bounds. The problem if you don't know the normalization of forward transform then you don't know the normalization of inverse.

Comment: @mathreadler hi, I don't have a strong background in math; could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Was the answer sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

A classical DCT-II transformation writes:

$$
D[u,v] = \frac{1}{4} C_u C_v \sum_{y=0}^7 \sum_{x=0}^7 I[x,y] \cos\frac{(2x+1)u\pi}{16} \cos\frac{(2y+1)v\pi}{16}
$$

I will leave the outer constant $\frac{1}{4} C_u C_v$ aside for the reasoning, and write the inner kernel:

$$C[u,v]= \cos\frac{(2x+1)u\pi}{16} \cos\frac{(2y+1)v\pi}{16}.$$

As a consequence, the summation rewrites:

$$\sum_{y=0}^7 \sum_{x=0}^7 I[x,y]C[u,v].$$

You can find an upper bound by maximizing each product, choosing $I[x,y]$ carefully: if $C[u,v]>0$, pick $I[x,y]=127$, otherwise set $I[x,y]=-128$ (hence each $I[x,y]C[u,v]$ product is maximally positive). Similarly, a lower bound is given for $I[x,y]=-128$ when $C[u,v]>0$ and $I[x,y]=127$ when $C[u,v]\le 0$.

Thus, you just have to produce a matrix of the signs of $C[u,v]$, and turn the +1 into 127, and the -1 into -128, and compute both sums of products.

Plugin in the outer constant $\frac{1}{4} C_u C_v$ will give you possible lower and upper bounds.

Two last thoughts: first, your input matrix might be integer-valued, hence you can add some rounding to the above values. Second, the input values are signed integers in the $[-128,127]$ range, which is not the most usual. Pixel values have often in  $[0,255]$. I thus suspect that an offset could be consider as well.